# Error using Using operand and XmlElement

Tags: vb.net, using-statement

my code is like this:

```
        Using StateProv As XmlElement = CType(hotelSearch.SelectSingleNode("/ota:OTA_HotelSearchRQ/ota:Criteria/ota:Criterion/ota:Address/ota:StateProv", nsmgr), XmlElement) 'i am getting error in this line....
        StateProv.SetAttribute("StateCode", BLLHotel_Search.StateCode)
        StateProv.ChildNodes(0).InnerText = BLLHotel_Search.StateName
    End Using

error:
"using operand of type 'System.xml.xmlelement' must implement 'system.idisposable'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use *Using*

Just try

```
Dim StateProv As XmlElement = CType(hotelSearch.SelectSingleNode("/ota:OTA_HotelSearchRQ/ota:Criteria/ota:Criterion/ota:Address/ota:StateProv", nsmgr), XmlElement) 'i am getting error in this line.... 
StateProv.SetAttribute("StateCode", BLLHotel_Search.StateCode) 
StateProv.ChildNodes(0).InnerText = BLLHotel_Search.StateName
```

From documentation of using

> The using keyword :
>
> As a statement,
>   when it defines a scope at the end of
>   which an object will be disposed.

To check if it has a value compare it to `Nothing`

```
Dim node As XmlNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//")
If node IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim attribute As XmlAttribute = node.Attributes(0)
End If
```

Try this

```
Dim StateProv As XmlElement = CType(hotelSearch.SelectSingleNode("/ota:OTA_HotelSearchRQ/ota:Criteria/ota:Criterion/ota:Address/ota:StateProv", nsmgr), XmlElement) 

If StateProv IsNot Nothing Then
        StateProv.SetAttribute("StateCode", BLLHotel_Search.StateCode) 
        StateProv.ChildNodes(0).InnerText = BLLHotel_Search.StateName 
End If
```

Comment: i know but what if i will not get any value from selectsinglenode..?

Comment: actually what i want is that ..if i not get any xmlelement returned from file line then below 2 line should not be executed...and i think
using is good option to do this

Comment: i know we can use nothing in if statement..but please tell me what will i have to do..if i want to do using here...

Comment: To make use of using the object must implement **system.idisposable** which it seems that *XmlElement* does not.

Comment: thanks you sir.. its a good solution... i will implement it.. but please explain me if i want to use Using then what i will have to do.. i have to and where i wil have to implement IDisposable interface (according to error)